# add file from state to firestore collection Firestore Firebase ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux-firebase

I have Action component, where I am adding new `projects` to `firestore.collection`

```
 export const createProject = (project) => {
      return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {

            const firestore = getFirestore();

            firestore.collection('projects').add({
                ...project

            }).then(() => {
                dispatch({})
            }).catch((err) => {
                dispatch({});
            })
        }
    };
```

And I have component:

```
state = {
      title: '',
      content: '',
      file: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleOnFileChange = (e) => {
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : file
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log(this.state)
    }



    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

       <input type="text" id="title" onChange={this.handleOnFileChange}/>

       <textarea id="content" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>

       <input type="file" id="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

    </form>

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        createProject: (project) => dispatch(createProject(project)) 
    }
}
```

And after submit I am getting this error :
×
"FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom File object (found in field file)"

if I delete `file` from `state`, and try to `add` that state, without `file`, everything works fine, and my projects are adding to `firestore.collection`, but i need to add to `firestore.collection` everything from state (`title`, `content` and `file`)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, this is because you try to save to Firestore an object of type [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) which is not supported. See here the supported data types https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types.

So, either you use a property (or several properties) of the File object, like, for example, the name, the size or the type.

or you modify your code to save the file to Cloud Storage for Firebase which is the dedicated Firebase service for storing and serving files, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

It all depends on your exact need: saving the file or only some of its properties.